# mysql CREATE trigger not working, error while creating the trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, oracle-sqldeveloper

My teacher sent me this code, we are doing mysql, last time she sent oraclesql code, so this might be oraclesql:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Kontrola
ON DATABASE
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE
AS PRINT "Brisanje i izmena nad objektima nije dozvoljena!"
ROLLBACK
```

And it says:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON IZVRSIOCI
AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
PRINT 'Novi zapis u tabeli'
END' **at line 2**

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher?

Comment: The error message references MariaDB, a different database engine than either Oracle or MySQL.  And it references code that doesn't appear in the code you posted.  You've tagged this for Oracle SQL Developer, XAMPP, and phpMyAdmin.  I can't envision how any of those three are relevant here-- are you actually using one or more of these tools in this question?

Comment: MariaDB have no DDL triggers. So this code is not applicable in this DBMS (even if it was correct).